# Disable navigation bar transparency while pushViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have TableViewController embed in NavigationController, also I have DetailedViewController that should be opened when cell on in TableViewController is selected.

So I calling

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailedViewController, animated: true)
```

My navigation bar settings:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .green
```

DetailedViewController's navigation bar is hidden

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

and while I see push animation from TableViewController to DetailedViewController I can see some of content from Controller that stands behind TableViewController though navigation bar that becomes transparent for this transition.

What can I do with it?

Comment: I am not sure what your issue is about, but I guess if you set the navigationBar of the view controller (TableVC) to hidden before pushing the DetailedVC and then in the completion you set it hidden false again, you do the trick.

Comment: "DetailedViewController's navigation bar is hidden". Note that conceptually there is only a single navigation bar in a UINavigationController, not one per pushed view controller. The single bar can be hidden/unhidden. So where (in which method) in the DetailedViewController do you set isNavigationBarHidden = true?

Answer (score -2):

This is compilers undefined behaviour, You can achieve your goal with the following operations.

1) Select Navigation controller-> Navigation Bar.
2) Untick the translucent property. (See editor pane).
3) Also hide the the navigation Bar from storyboard.
4) Show the navigation bar in view controller where it is required.

//Code to show navigation bar:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```